# JavaScript Undefined Result While Printing An Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I'm new to the raw JavaScript side of web development so I decided to learn. I know the basics of programming and I've ran into something I can't seem to fix. While playing with arrays in JavaScript I wanted to make a function to print everything out So I created something like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Learning JavaScript </title>
<script>
    var names = new Array("Connor <br />", "Shane <br />", "Ty <br />", "Brandon <br />");

    function printArray (){
        for(x=0; x < names.length; x++)
            document.write(names[x]);
    }

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        document.write(printArray());
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It prints out the names but after the names it also has another piece of text called 'undefined'. It looks like this.

```
Connor 
Shane 
Ty 
Brandon 
undefined
```

I've tired moving the condition around a bunch in the for loop and getting no where. I think for me it would be great to understand why the 'undefined' is there and how I could possibly avoid these situations in the future while I'm actually doing a project. Any help would be great. Thanks :)

Comment: The `undefined` bit is the value returned when you call `printArray`. Replace the line `document.write(printArray());` with `printArray();`

Comment: Also, avoid `document.write`

Comment: You have in your code 2x `document.write`, the first (in your function) does the write, while the other does: `1:` Executes `(printArray())` and `write` .... well... undefined cause nothing to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
document.write(printArray());
```

is using `document.write()` to print the return value of the function `printArray()`. Your function prints the array of names as you'd expect but doesn't actually return a value, so your outer call gets `undefined` and prints that. You can see this happening if you add something like `return "someString";` as the last line of `printArray()`;

Actually, all you need is

```
<body>
    <script>
        printArray();
    </script>
</body>
```

I understand that this is a learning exercise, but for future reference `document.write()` is not really good practice. Setting the document body directly with something like

```
document.body.innerHTML = "someHTML<br>";
```

is a better method.

Comment: Ohhhh thank you! I've been using JQuery for some time and thought I needed to learn the actual JavaScript not the framework. A tutorial on YouTube said if I wanted something to appear on screen then I had to use document.write(); Thank you for getting back to me so quickly!

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/pewig/2/edit)**

```
var names = [ "Connor <br>", "Shane <br>", "Ty <br>", "Brandon <br>"];

var html = "";
function printArray (){
   for(var x=0; x < names.length; x++){
      html += names[x];   // Populate string with array values
   }
   document.body.innerHTML = html; // Append string only once
}

printArray();
```

`document.write` is a form of *evil*, should be replaced in favor of other methods like `innerHTML`.

Use an *string* representation to hold all your extracted HTML and append to the desired element only once.

[Why is document.write considered a "bad practice"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

Comment: [*document.write*](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/webappapis.html#document.write()) is not deprecated. It is in current versions of both the [W3C HTML5](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/webappapis.html#document.write()) and [WHATWG HTML "Living Standard"](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/webappapis.html#document.write()).

Comment: @RobG ups true, I used a wrong term, as your link sais: `!! Warning This method has very idiosyncratic behavior.` Should we deprecate it? That's another question.

Comment: Okay I think I understand what's going on there, thanks for the help :)

Comment: @ConnorGaunt No problem. Think about the use of the code I suggested.

Comment: I will look into innerHTML, I must have been watching an old set of tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

What Roko wrote and move the `<br>` from your data to the code.

```
var names = [ "Connor", "Shane", "Ty", "Brandon"];

var html = "";
function printArray (){
   for(var x=0; x < names.length; x++){
      html += names[x] + '<br>';   // Populate string with array values
   }
   document.body.innerHTML = html; // Append string only once
}

printArray();
```

This makes it easier to change your html in, for example:

```
      html += '<p>' + names[x] + '</p>';   // Populate string with array values
```

Comment: Ahhh thank you, I see how removing the break out of the data would be better in general. That way I could use that data somewhere else without the break. Thanks.

Comment: `o_O` Instead of posting a duplicate answer you've could comment on the already existing one by just noting: `html += names[x] + '<br>';`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: I didn't think of that, but you're right, sorry.